# scheduling dynamic jobs in resque scheduler

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, resque

I'm trying to test out scheduling jobs in future using rails 3 and resque scheduler:

Following is the code I'm using but I'm getting NoMethodError set_schedule.

```
 Resque.set_schedule("1", {
  :cron => "30 6 * * 1",
  :class => "Notify",
  :queue => "username",
  :message => 'notification message'      
})
```

I tried using a simple enqueue `Resque.enqueue(Notify, params[:message])` and this works fine.

UPDATE:

Following is the error I'm getting:

```
undefined method `set_schedule' for Resque Client connected to redis://bass.redistogo.com:9064/0:Module
```

Comment: can you post the exact error message you're getting? did you require resuqe scheduler or did you install it as a gem?

Comment: Error: undefined method `set_schedule' for Resque Client connected to redis://bass.redistogo.com:9064/0:Module

Comment: thats the error? just one line?

Comment: Yes that's the error I'm getting. Here is the additional message: NoMethodError in NotifyController#sendmessage

undefined method `set_schedule' for Resque Client connected to redis://bass.redistogo.com:9064/0:Module

Comment: can you also post your controller code here?

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling in resque is (now) in a separate gem. You can find all the information you need at:

https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler/

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
require 'resque_scheduler'
```

before `class NotifyController < ActionController::Base`

Comment: LoadError in NotifyController#sendMessage - no such file to load -- resque_scheduler

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same problem. It looks like there is a difference between the v1.9.9 gem file resque_scheduler.rb on this site, and that being downloaded from rubygems.org.

You need to get the 2.0.0 pre-release, and also enable dynamic scheduling using :

```
Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I have 2.0.0.d of the gem and it accepts Rescue::Scheduler.dynamic = true (before 2.0 it was complaining about that), but still says set_schedule is undefined.